# Determining UTF encoding STRICTLY based off input and output

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have written a small "[post processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_processor)" for our CNC machines': given a handful of inputs, it generates [g-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) that is more efficient than the machines' built-in functions.

The problem is that different machines in our shop use different encodings, so anything above 128 on the ASCII table comes out garbled.

I would love to output the correct encoding for each machine... But I have no (real) way to find out what that is; my best option is "guess and check". For example... If I have a comment in my code that says:

```
(Wall: 5°)
```

On `machine A` that becomes `(Wall: 5Â°)`.

On `machine B` that becomes `(Wall: 5B0)`.

I can feed these machines any character, and I can see how they interpret it.

How, if at all, can I use *that* information (and *only* that information) to determine the encoding scheme?

Thanks for any tips, advice, links, or reading you can provide (yes, [I've read this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)).

Comment: I assume it is a one-time operation? You could compile an input that exists of all code points from 128-255 and see how that outputs on each machine? You can then trivially map that output back to a code page by manually comparing the output to known code pages.

Comment: `°` is Unicode codepoint `U+00B0 DEGREE SIGN`. Machine A is using UTF-8, where U+00B0 is encoded as bytes `C2 B0`. Machine B is using Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 or other similar Latin encoding, where U+00B0 is encoded as byte `B0`.